# sorl-thumbnail is not working in django

Tags: python, django, django-templates, thumbnails, sorl-thumbnail

I am using sorl-thumbnail to dynamically create thumbnails in my django project.

This is my HTML code is:

```
<html>
<head><title>mypage</title>
<% load thumbnail %}
<div class="logo">
       <a href="">
    {% thumbnail "http://www.aino.se/media/i/logo.png" "40x40" as im %}
        <img src="{{ im.url }}">
        {% endthumbnail %}
       </a>
</div>
</html>
```

And this is my `settings.py`

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    ..... 

    'django.middleware.cache.UpdateCacheMiddleware',
    "django.middleware.cache.FetchFromCacheMiddleware",

    # Uncomment the next line for simple clickjacking protection:
    # 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)


INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
     .......
    "sorl.thumbnail",
)

CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.filebased.FileBasedCache',
        'LOCATION': 'd:/code/,
    }
}
```

I am not getting any error and no thumbnails either!

Comment: Do you have an image library installed like PIL? http://sorl-thumbnail.readthedocs.org/en/latest/requirements.html#image-library

Comment: And is this true for your installation? `--- JPEG support available
--- ZLIB (PNG/ZIP) support available`

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. After some investigation I found out that my webserver (in my case nginx) had no write access to the `MEDIA_ROOT`.

Somehow, sorl-thumbnail fails silently in this case. Giving access to the nginx user solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your image link is valid? Try to catch this issue by  `{% empty %}` feature:

```
{% thumbnail "http://www.aino.se/media/i/logo.png" "40x40" as im %}
    <img src="{{ im.url }}">
{% empty %}
    <p>No image</p>
{% endthumbnail %}
```

As documentation says:

> Using the empty feature, the empty section is rendered when the source
>   is resolved to an empty value or an invalid image source...: